# ¿Cómo puedo relacionar correctamente un empleado, cliente y ventas?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo un problema al realizar unas consultas a mi base de datos. Tengo las siguientes tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla `cliente` como la de `empleado` tengo como clave primaria el `idpersona` de la tabla `persona`. Tengo separado los atributos en una tabla `persona(nombre, cedula, direccion)` porque son atributos que tiene el cliente como el empleado. Pero parece que no es la forma correcta de hacerlo. Voy a poner aquí un par de consultas que intento hacer:

1. Obtener `inventa`, `fecha`, `importe`, y `nombre` del comprador de una compra realizada en febrero. (esta consulta no hay problema.)

   ```
   SELECT
   v.idventa,
   v.fecha,
   v.importe,
   p.nombre as comprador

   FROM
   ventas as v
   join cliente as c on v.cliente_persona_idpersona = c.persona_idpersona
   join persona as p on p.idpersona = c.persona_idpersona
   WHERE
   v.fecha = 'febrero'
   ```
2. ¿Cómo agregar a esa consulta anterior el nombre de la persona que realizó la venta, si tanto el vendedor como el cliente están ligados a la misma tabla `persona`, la cual tiene el atributo `nombre`.
3. Según mi modelo no permite que el mismo empleado realize una compra. Es decir si en la tienda hay solo una persona encargada de realizar las ventas, y de pronto él necesita comprar algo como lo registra, si en mi tabla `ventas` no puedo poner el mismo id de vendedor como comprador, ¿debería separar una tabla `cliente` con todos sus atributos y una tabla `empleado` con sus atributos aunque estos sean iguales a los de `cliente`?

Dicho de otra forma, ¿cómo puedo hacer que un vendedor pueda comprar también y registrarlo en la base de datos?

Comment: *si en mi tabla ventas no puedo poner el el mismo id de vendedor como comprador*: No veo que tengas esta restricción en tu modelo. ¿Qué impide que la tabla `ventas` tenga el mismo valor para ambos campos  `empleado_persona_idpersona` y `cliente_persona_idpersona`?

Comment: amigo tienes razón si pude realizar la venta con el mismo id , anterior mente tenia otros atributos y no se que hice pero no se podia ingresar el mismo ID¿ como puedo darse cuenta que si es posible registrar el mismo empleado como comprador???? como agrego esa restricción??

Comment: Disculpa. No entiendo la pregunta. ¿cual restricción quieres agregar?

Comment: queria decir ¿Como se dio cuenta que no tenia esa restricción? en la base de datos (la que supone que impedía que tenga el mismo valor el campo empleado_persona_idpersona y cliente_persona_idpersona):o

Comment: Pues no lo sabía del todo. Obviamente, cabía la posibilidad de que tuvieras un trigger definido en la tabla `ventas` que verifica que ambos campos no pueden tener el mismo valor. Pero, como no mencionastes nada de eso, por defecto, el modelo que tienes no impone ninguna restricción de esa clase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agregando a la excelente respuesta de Marcos Gallardo, si no necesitas devolver ninguno de los campos específicos de las tablas `empleado` y `cliente`, entonces, no necesitas incluir estas tablas en tu consulta.

En tu caso, la consulta la puedes simplificar a:

```
select v.idventa,
       v.fecha,
       v.importe,
       c.nombre as nombre_cliente,
       e.nombre as nombre_empleado
  from ventas v
  join persona c
    on c.idpersona = v.cliente_persona_idpersona
  join persona e
    on e.idpersona = v.empleado_persona_idpersona
 where v.fecha = 'febrero'
```

Si llegas a necesitar campos como `cliente.ultima_compra` o algo por el estilo en el `SELECT`, entonces sí es necesario agregar la tabla adicional a la consulta para poder acceder a ese campo.

---

Ahora bien, anticipando que van a haber situaciones donde vas a necesitar incluir las tablas `cliente` y `empleado` a la consulta, hay que admitir que se puede volver bien fastidioso de tener que hacer joins con tantas tablas. Además, aunque es posible hacer joins con la tabla `persona` con diferentes alias en una misma consulta, puede volverse un poco confuso, y fácilmente puede llevarte a cometer errores.

Algo que puedes hacer, para simplificar el uso de tus tablas, es crear vistas que esconden el hecho de que compartes datos de clientes y empleados en la tabla `persona`. Hacer esto no es una violación de los principios de normalización que has puesto en práctica.

Ejemplo:

```
create view vw_empleado as
select e.persona_idpersona as idempleado,
       e.usuario,
       e.clave,
       p.nombre,
       p.cedula,
       p.direccion
  from empleado e
  join persona p
    on p.idpersona = e.persona_idpersona;

create view vw_cliente as
select c.persona_idpersona as idcliente,
       c.ultima_compra,
       p.nombre,
       p.cedula,
       p.direccion
  from cliente c
  join persona p
    on p.idpersona = c.persona_idpersona;
```

De esta forma, sin importar cuales campos necesitas, puedes usar las vistas para tus consultas, y es menos confuso de esa manera. Por ejemplo, tu consulta usando las vistas sería:

```
select v.idventa,
       v.fecha,
       v.importe,
       c.nombre as nombre_cliente,
       e.nombre as nombre_empleado
  from ventas v
  join vw_cliente c
    on c.idcliente = v.cliente_persona_idpersona
  join vw_empleado e
    on e.idempleado = v.empleado_persona_idpersona
 where v.fecha = 'febrero'
```

Comment: amigo muchas gracias me ah servido mucho la información, no había echo nunca una vista pero ahora veo que es bastante util lo voy estudiar mas un saludo

Answer (score 3):

> Como agregar a esa consulta anterior el nombre de la persona que realizo la venta, si tanto el vendedor como el cliente están ligados a la misma tabla persona la cual tiene el atributo nombre.

La solución es uniendo (`join`) la tabla `empleado` y nuevamente nuevamente la tabla `persona` (con otro alias) pero esta otra vez indicando el `id` del empleado.

Por ejemplo, así:

```
SELECT
  V.idventa,
  V.fecha,
  V.importe,
  P.nombre AS comprador
  PV.nombre AS vendedor

FROM ventas AS V
  JOIN cliente AS C 
    ON V.cliente_persona_idpersona = C.persona_idpersona
  JOIN persona AS P
    ON P.idpersona = C.persona_idpersona
  JOIN empleado AS E
    ON V.empleado_persona_idpersona = E.persona_idpersona
  JOIN persona AS PV 
    ON PV.idpersona = E.persona_idpersona
WHERE
  V.fecha = 'febrero'
```

> como puedo hacer que un vendedor pueda comprar también y registrarlo en la base de datos?

Como dice @sstan en su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36195/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-relacionar-correctamente-un-empleado-cliente-y-ventas/36196#comment60814_36195), tu esquema de tablas aparentemente no parece tener ninguna limitación, por lo que debería ser trivial, que un vendedor también sea comprador.

Comment: amigo muchas gracias eso quiere decir que la relación entre las tablas esta bien?

Comment: Para lo que estas buscando hacer, te diría que si.