# Mostrar datos personales del cliente y empleado que participan en un pedido

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy atrapada en un problema de SQL y espero poder conseguir aquí cualquier ayuda por mínima que sea!
Lo que quiero lograr es mostrar en un listado el nombre y apellido del cliente y del empleado que participan en un pedido! lo que me causa problemas es a la hora de hacer la consulta porque los datos personales de clientes y empleados se encuentran en una misma tabla... me recomendaron el uso de alias pero aún asi no puedo lograr nada! adjunto la imagen de las tablas y el código que estoy probando
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
`SELECT * FROM pedidos p
INNER JOIN detalle_pedido dp ON p.`pedido_id`=dp.`rela_pedido`
INNER JOIN pedidos_estados pe ON p.`rela_pedido_estado`=pe.`pedido_estado_id`
INNER JOIN clientes c ON p.`rela_cliente`=c.`cliente_id` 
INNER JOIN empleados e ON p.`rela_empleado`=e.`empleado_id`
INNER JOIN personas_fisicas pf ON ...`
```

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que en 2 tablas?, yo noto una que es clientes y otra que es empleados

Comment: Te explico: no dije que hay 2 tablas, dije que cuando quiero acceder a los datos personales de clientes y de empleados no se como hacer la consulta, porque en la ultima linea de la consulta luego del "ON" tendria que  poner una de las dos [clientes o empleados para igualar el fk de la otra tabla] (¿No se si puedo poner las 2 con un "AND"?)

Comment: Segundo, tengo la necesidad de diferenciar las personas físicas y personas jurídicas porque  como se sabe una persona jurídica(empresas u organismos) no tienen los mismos atributos que una persona física

Comment: Entenido @Ruth gracias por los detalles aclaratorios :), leeré de nuevo para ver si puedo aportar una solución.

Comment: @BetaM dale! Gracias a vos desde ya

Answer (score 0):

Tome de esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36195/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-relacionar-correctamente-un-empleado-cliente-y-ventas?rq=1) la respuesta marcada como correcta y pude resolver mi problema!

1. Creación de vistas (view).
2. Join utilizando las mismas.

Les dejo habilitado para que les sea mas fácil llegar a una solución rápida! Gracias